# 3D interpolation function

Tags: numerical-methods, 3d, interpolation, interpolation-theory

I've got a [3D figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNPg2.png) created using around 30k points and has different regions colored in an specific way according to some unrelated variables that come from a project I'm creating.
Taking in consideration that I've got the exact values of each point in each region is there a way to interpolate the values into a function that creates an approximation of each space? like how Lagrange Interpolation does it but in 2D

I'm mostly looking for names of methods so I can try and implement them

Comment: Your problem feels a little ill-defined, but another approach you might consider is a sort of Gaussian Blur on the data: wherever you want to compute the value of the function, take the few closest values you can find and weight them by distance from the point. As long as your filter function 'blows up' at zero distance (or becomes zero at a distance that's no greater than a point-to-point distance) this should give a smooth interpolation.

Comment: Also, you should be aware that Lagrange polynomials are notoriously unstable with respect to small changes in values being interpolated; they may not be what you want to model your approach after...

Answer (score 1):

Are all of the edges of your regions lines, planes, and polyhedra? It might help to look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system Barycentric Coordinates. You'll have to split everything into triangles/tetrahedra first.